# Getting exact substring that satisfies regex's match

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to get the indices of the regular expression match below:

```
input : ab 
regex: a(?=b)
```

The `Match` object contains information on the actual matched part of the string(`a`) and does not include the zero-width assertions that were required for the match to succeed. I want to be able to capture the exact substring that satisfies this match. I don't want to have to expand the string manually to do so. It seems to me there should be a method somewhere in the FCL.

**Edit**:

Just to make things more clear as there are recommendations as to not using lookaheads. I am well aware that I shouldn't be using lookaheads when I want to actually match a part of the string. However, the application I am working on receives a series of regular expressions to be used in a preprocessing stage. These regular expressions are out of my control. I cannot guarantee that they properly match the zero-width assertions. In this stage the matched regular expressions are replaced with a piece of text. In order for the following regular expression replace procedure to work, I need to be able to capture the substring in the string that satisfies the regular expression. Consider the code below:

```
string input = "abcdefg";
Regex regex = new Regex("a(?=b)");
Match m = regex.Match(input);
regex.Replace(m.Value, "z").Dump();
```

First notice that I want the replacement to happen only in the portion of the input that the match occurred and not the entire input. This is very important as I don't want all the matches to be replaced just yet. The code above's output is 'a' and not 'z'. The reason for that is that `m.Value` is `a` and the regex wouldn't replace a single `a` with `z`. It would replace the a found in 'ab' with 'z'. I want to be able to pass 'ab' to the `Replace` function.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: So you want to get "ab" right?

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Could you please provide more examples (possible input string, what you want to match, and not want to). If I had understood what you want, I think lookahead is not the best operator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong API for controlling the replacement: rather than passing the match back to regex, use [the four-argument overload of `Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fky5t5f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that gives you tighter control over what is being replaced in the original string, and what parts of the string to consider for the replacement:

```
string input = "abcdefg";
Regex regex = new Regex("a(?=b)");
regex.Replace(input , "z", 1, 0).Dump();
```

Only the first match will be replaced, starting at the index zero. If you would like to continue replacing additional matches, change the last parameter to the new starting index. Keep the third parameter at `1`, so as to make at most one replacement.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know that overload existed. I should have checked that first myself :)